# Loop Through Specific Worksheets and Return specific Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script. It is meant to run through specific sheet and return values. So in summary ignore some of the sheets. I did a nested loop ignoring some of the sheets and return values but it does not work. \

I want to be able to extract data from some of them and ignore the rest using the sheet names.  The problem is it returns the name of each sheet 22 times in column, so I would have Sydney in the first column 20 times and then Melbourne in column number 2 20 times.

I want the name of all sheets to come in the first column.

```
Sub FinalGO()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim L As Long

    nowMonth = Month(Now)
    nowYear = Year(Now)
    Nowday = Day(Now)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Summary " & Nowday & "-" & nowMonth & "-" & nowYear

    'do nothing

    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Insert

    For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Project Name"

        For Each WS In Worksheets
            Select Case WS.Name
                Case "Prices", "Home Page", "Model Digaram", "Validation & Checks", "Model Start-->", "Input|Assumptions", "Cost Assumption"
                Case Else
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = WS.Name
            End Select
        Next WS
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add more detail on what is not working? A thought - your inner loop overwrites the same cell - `Cells(i, 1)` - because `i` does not increment until the next iteration of the *outer* loop.

Comment: Please be clear on what is your requirement, what is the error and in which state its not working.

Comment: Dear all the problem is The problem is it returns the name of each sheet 22 times in column, so I would have Sydney in the first column 20 times and then Melbourne in column number 2 20 times. 

I want the name of all sheets to come in the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Through Worksheets to Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FinalGO()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' When using turning ScreenUpdating off, it is wise to use an Error Handler,
    ' so when an error occurs, it will get turned on again.
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim ws As Worksheet     ' Current Worksheet
    Dim i As Long           ' Row (Cell) Counter
    Dim strName As String   ' New Worksheet Name

    ' Determine New Worksheet Name.
    strName = "Summary " & Day(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Year(Now)

    ' In This Workbook (The Workbook Containing This Code)
    With ThisWorkbook
         ' Check if New Worksheet already exists.
         On Error Resume Next
         Set ws = .Worksheets(strName)
         If Err Then  ' Does NOT exist.
              On Error GoTo 0
            Else      ' DOES exist.
              GoTo AlreadyDoneToday
         End If

         ' Reenable error handling.
         On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        ' Add a New Worksheet to the last position in This Workbook.
        .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        ' In the New Worksheet.
        With .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            ' Rename New Worksheet. If you already have used this code today,
            ' this line will produce an error. Delete the sheet or...
            .Name = strName
            ' Write to cell A1 in New Worksheet.
            .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Project Name"
            ' Reset Row (Cells) Counter , because 1st already contains a value.
            i = 1
            ' Loop through worksheets of This Workbook (.Parent).
            For Each ws In .Parent.Worksheets
                ' Check the Name of the Current Worksheet.
                Select Case ws.Name
                    ' Do Nothing.
                    Case "Prices", "Home Page", "Model Digaram", _
                            "Validation & Checks", "Model Start-->", _
                            "Input|Assumptions", "Cost Assumption"
                    Case Else
                        ' Count Rows (Cells).
                        i = i + 1
                        ' Write name of Current Worksheet to cell in current
                        ' Row and first column of New Worksheet.
                        .Cells(i, 1).Value = ws.Name
                End Select
            Next
        End With
    End With

Success:

    MsgBox "The operation finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

SafeExit:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

AlreadyDoneToday:

    MsgBox "You have already done this today.", vbExclamation, "Already done."
    GoTo SafeExit

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred. Error '" & Err.Number & "': " _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    GoTo SafeExit

End Sub
```